# How to communicate with popup.js and content script with chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

This is what I am doing right now:

Manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "my_extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "my_description",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "my extension",
        "default_icon": "logo.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts" : [{
        "matches": [
            "*://*/*",
            "file://*/*"
          ],
       "js" : ["contentscript.js"]
    }],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
      ]


}
```

Contentscript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      sendResponse({hello:'asdfsafsd'})
    });
```

Popup.js (which is attached to my html of popup)

```
    $("#calculate").click(() => {

        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){
            console.log(tab.index);
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.index,{greeting: "hello"},(response)=>{
                console.log(response.hello)
            })
        });



    })
```

When I click the button #click_me I get the following:

```
Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'wat' of undefined
at chrome-extension://pmclodhoknpghfkblogphfmecjnopfjm/popup.js:6:50
```

Comment: You get the what? there seems to something crucial missing.

Comment: Sorry fixed that for you.

Comment: Do you have a background.js as well? Or only popup + content?

Comment: The posted code must be incomplete since it didn't have "wat" anywhere. Try to make a real [MCVE](/help/mcve) so we can reproduce the problem.